# Keyboard driver malfunction on ThinkPad T470s running Linux Mint (possibly after installing Virtualbox)?

Tags: linux, keyboard, linux-mint

Recently, my Lenovo ThinkPad T470s laptop started acting up: when booted to Linux Mint 19.3 (it has dual-boot option with stock Windows 10 as an alternative), the system acts like left Control key is constantly pressed. If I change key mapping in BIOS setting (ThinkPads have an option to "swap" Fn and Control key functions), Fn key is being detected as constantly pressed instead.

Why do I believe it is a programmatical error instead of hardware failure?

- The behavior doesn't reproduce when booted to Windows 10
- The behavior doesn't reproduce in Linux Mint 19.3 Live USB
- If the keyboard is programmatically detached via xinput (see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard) and then reattached (i.e. `xinput float X` `xinput reattach X Y`), the problem stops occuring until the next reboot. In fact, it's gone once `xinput float` is executed.
- I've never noticed the problem when I've started Linux without `lightdm` (via inline editing grub config during boot)
- `evtest` produces no output when no buttons are pressed on keyboard (on the other hand, I've tried physically "sticking" the right Control key with putting weight on top of it prior to launching `evtest` and there was output of `KEY_RIGHTCTRL` scan codes being detected), also producing no output when left Control key is pressed.

I still am not 100% sure that it is not a hardware issue, that's why I've ordered a replacement from AliExpress - I'll provide an update here when the replacement keyboard arrives and is installed. I've tried to remove keyboard physically - obviously the problem never occurs then (I use external keyboard to verify).

The major things I've done to my system before I've started noticing it was installing `virtualbox-6.1` package from official PPA. Although running `apt purge virtualbox-6.1` didn't solve the issue at all.

Obviously, I can reinstall the OS and the problem would 99% be gone, but I wouldn't like to do so, instead trying to understand what is going on.

**UPDATE**

So far I've tried the following suggestions with problem still reproducing:

- check `dconf` for any strange parameters
- replace display manager (to `sddm`), purge and reinstall `lightdm`. The problem doesn't reproduce on login screen but does once I log in and Cinnamon is launched.
- replace DE: I've switched to XFCE and problem still reproduces there

Now that two steps above gave me an idea - create a blank new user and try logging in, I did exactly that. Guess what? The problem is gone when I am inside that user's Cinnamon session. If I switch users, the problem is back.

**So it is definitely something with a user configuration.**

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks to the advices both in comments and only existing answer it really encountered to me that I can use test user to nail the exact difference making the problem appear.

**Apparently, wiping `~/.config/pulse/` helps. I do not understand why, but it does.**

Logically, pulseaudio client is one of the things starting when the user logs in. Why it does affect the keyboard - it's another question. I will dig in this direction but for now, the case is more or less closed.

Comment: Try if another keyboard layout reproduces the same problem. This [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17626/how-can-i-restore-default-keyboard-shortcuts) might be useful if it applies to your setup.

Comment: @harrymc - with Russian, German and US English layouts the problem is still reproduced. I will check the idea with shortcut customization, though.

Comment: Did you try to **purge** and reinstall `lightdm`?  If it doesn't work  try some alternatives to lightdm and switch among them, to see if it happens only with  lightdm. When you disinstalled virtualbox and logged via lightdm did you experienced this problem?

Comment: So, my dconf configuration is pretty much vanilla in terms of keyboard. Nothing stands out in accessibility settings as well.

Installed `sddm`, the problem is still reproduced. Purged and reinstalled `lightdm`, it's the same.
As I am able to enter characters normally in password prompt at login screen (when Cinnamon didn't kick in yet), I will try replacing Cinnamon with a different DE and see if it helps.

Comment: See my update above. I am currently researching if there are user-based launch configs (like autorun in old Windows) which run BG applications capable of screwing up the keyboard

Comment: Good. Now in `~/.kde/` there is the main part of the user settings... with a lot of config files e.g. in `~/kde/share/config`... you should freeze your settings (did you installed `timeshift`?) and go to check the config files one by one... or better taking out them all and adding them bunch by bunch (error finding procedure: you remove them all and check what happens: if the problem persist you put back all & search elsewhere, else you start to put back in bunches/branches; when the problem appears newly you take off again the last buch and search one by one within it...(continue)

Comment: Note that it is possible you have some databases inside the `~/.kde` tree... it can be risky to tamper with them... BTW something like `timeshift` can help you. Moreover, it is advisable to reduce at minimum the tasks that start automatically  before  starting to remove the branches of settings... just to have a minumum impact.

Comment: Try to move config files from the user's root folder to the blank new user's until the problem occurs.

Comment: Seems like my advice helped to pinpoint the problem, so I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment of moving config files from the user's root folder
to the blank new user's until the problem re-occurs,
the poster has localized the problem to `~/.config/pulse/`.

Removing this solved the problem. For good measures one should also run
the command `pulseaudio -k` to kill the currently running pulseaudio instance.

It seems like pulseaudio got confused by your keyboard and decided it needs to
handle volume keys that perhaps do not exist on it,
by this way lousing up the keyboard interface.

Removing the above has erased this erroneous setting.

Answer (score 1):

#### Situation

The OP experienced a keyboard problem (acting as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> was always pressed) after installing some software and upgrading the system. He seems noticing it after some time (he states *recently*), so it cannot be surely related with a specific program or package. It can be moreover related with an hardware failure.

#### Backup

Step zero, **make a backup**: it can be a full backup, your important data must always be backed up and it is useful your personal settings too.

Take a look at e.g. `timeshift` for the system side. If such a system had already been installed before the problem arose - assuming that it is not a hardware problem - this would have allowed to restore the system to the last date with a properly functioning OS, and then proceed step by step to find where the problem was introduced. Now it allows you to experiment and, if necessary, to return to the current situation.

#### Step by step procedure

First it should be ascertained if the present issue is hardware or software related.

From the **hardware point of view**: it should be enough to substitue the keyboard with a new one surely working and to test the old one on another computer. Easy for a desktop uncosy for a laptop. It can be even used an external USB keyboard. If the problem persists with the USB one it cannot be related to the *built-in* one.

From the **software point of view**: the system up and running with the problem, passes before through some steps: BIOS, grub, kernel loading, graphic kernel, display manager, desktop environment (Kde,gnome...), user settings and user side programs.

- **BIOS** Swapping <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys in Bios the problem persists. This rules out an hardware key-jam cause; it still remain possible, but less probable, that the keyboard in its complex can have a failure.
- **Grub**: it allows you to select which OS starting with. Starting with different OS (windows) and finding no problem you may rule out any hardware origin.
- **USB loaded OS** Starting with a fresh OS installation (on the USB pen drive) you rule out any specific kernel problem too.
- Starting with special options from grub you can enter in a shell with no graphic engine started. You can check there if the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> problem persists. If not you can launch `startx` and see if it is generally `X` related.  You can even check with `su - user` before launching X, to search for user related problem under X.
- **Display manager**. The OP uses `lightdm`. There are many available and fortunately under Linux more than one at once can be installed. One is used. So it is possible to install another Display manager and check if the problem persists. Alternatively or once found in the desktop manager part, it is possible to remove and reinstall `lightdm`. Better to `purge` it.

  > Removing a package removes all packaged data, but leaves usually small (modified) user configuration files behind, in case the remove was an accident. Just issuing an installation request for the accidentally removed package will restore its function as before in that case.
  > On the other hand you can get rid of these leftovers by calling purge even on already removed packages. Note that this does not affect any data or configuration stored in your home directory.

  - The OP purged and reinstalled `lighdm`. Problem remained, so not related to the specific installation of `lighdm`.
  - Then he installed another DM. Again problem remained. It is not at all `lighdm` related.
- **Desktop environment**. Linux allows to install side by side more than one desktop environment (DE) at once, and to chose one at each login from the display manager. I do not suggest in general to install other DE if not required, because it is heavy (a lot of packages), it will slow down the updates, it can both cause confusion in the users and problem in third party software configuration and setups. Nonetheless, it can be tested if the problem depends from the DE adding a new user and logging from there, or cleaning (deleting) all the specific settings for the current user.

  - The OP rule out general DE problem, switching to XFCE (another DE) and finding again the problem logging with this DE.
- **User specific configuration**. Creating a new user and logging it is possible to check if it is specific of the user configuration/program. The OP fond no problem with the new user, and the problem back with the old user.

Now the field is narrowed down to the configuration files and settings of that specific user. It may depends from some settings as well as from some program automatically launched.

- Switch off as many automatically lauched on login program/tasks as possible.
- Move the confuguration directories branches and put back one by one.
- Check for other process running at that user login.

Note that it should be something that runs with both the DE and only for your user. In general give it a look to dmesg and other logs to check if something new happens when you log with your usual user.